# Merge 2 Datatables

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Datatable D1 with

```
DataTable 1
------------
ID  Name1
1   S1
2   S2
4   S4


DataTable 2
------------
ID  Name2
1   D1
2   D2
3   D3

Result:

FinalTable
-----------
ID  Name1  Name2
1   S1     D1
2   S2     D2
3          D3
4   S4
```

I tried the merge  ds1.Merge(dt2, true, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
This adds additional columns instead

Thanks
Sun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking to perform a FULL OUTER JOIN between two DataTables.  "[Full Outer Join of Two DataTables C# Code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/TwoDataTablesOuterJoin.aspx)" seems to be a decent-enough example, otherwise you now know what search terms to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL query

```
Select d1.id, d1.Name1, d2.Name2 from DataTable1 d1 join DataTable2 d2 on d1.id=d2.id
```

[Join (SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) would be a reference if you want one.